# How to design multiway- and many relationship combined in laravel?

Tags: laravel, database-design, eloquent

Tables:

- (Group) {group_id}
- (User) {user_id}
- (Permission) {permission_id}

I want to set permissions which apply to a group (all users) and a specific user (in a group). See ERD below.

I could ofcourse create two tables:

- (Group_Permission) {group_id, permission_id}
- (Group_User_permissions) {group_id, permission_id, user_id}

Or I could create one table:

- (Group_User_permissions) {group_id, permission_id, user_id}

And add all users when I update the permissions for a group.

I wonder if there is a more elegant solution to this in `laravel`.

[image: ERD]

Answer (score 0):

IMHO I would create these **relationships**:

1. **User** -> Many to Many -> **Group**
2. **Group** -> Many to Many -> **Permission**

In this way a *user* has many permissions through his own *groups*.

For the case of assigning permissions *directly to an user* you can define a group with a *name* equal to the *user username*, or something similar, so you can restrict that group in a way that is usable only by that user.

You can find reference of the relationships used above in the [laravel documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/eloquent-relationships).

Hope this could help.

Comment: This way you can't specify which user has what permissions in which group, right?